# Vectorize a function on a specific argument

Tags: vectorization, julia

Suppose I have a function

```
myfunc(a, x::Int64) = a * x
```

I want to vectorize the second argument only, so that I have something like

```
myfunc{N}(a, x::Array{Int64, N}) = map(x -> myfunc(a, x), x)
```

I know there are macro @vectorize_1arg or @vectorize_2arg.
However, those macros will vectorize all arguments.

Question: How to vectorize the function on a specific argument conveniently? Do I have to hard code like the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to extend functions where you want only the second arg vectorized, this should do it:

```
macro vectorize_on_2nd(S, f)
    S = esc(S); f = esc(f); N = esc(:N)
    quote
        ($f){$N}(a, x::AbstractArray{$S, $N}) =
            reshape([($f)(a, x[i]) for i in eachindex(x)], size(x))
    end
end
```

Used like this:

```
@vectorize_on_2nd Int64 myfunc
```

That should give you a `myfunc{N}(::Any, ::AbstractArray{Int64,N})` method.

Comment: Thanks! But it does not work in the case `myfunc(2, 1:10)`.

Comment: My apologies!  I've just edited the answer (changing Array to AbstractArray). Please have another go at it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this works

```
myfunc.([a],x)
```

as it will be vectorized over both arguments but [a] has only one entry.

Comment: You can also wrap your argument into a reference: `myfunc.(Ref(a), x)`